# Python threads mix the return values

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a code performing the same calculations for a different data. Function is running as a thread to save the time. I have 2 threads running at the same time, however, 90% of the time, the return from thread 1 has about 70% of the data that was used as args to another thread. Any idea how to fix this? As the return dataframes should not be mixed, however it appears that some time the values from the thread 2 return has values from thread 1. Here is my code:

A class to return values from threads:

```
from threading import Thread

class ThreadWithReturnValue(Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
                args=(), kwargs={}, Verbose=None):
        Thread.__init__(self, group, target, name, args, kwargs)
        self._return = None
    def run(self):
        if self._target is not None:
            self._return = self._target(*self._args,
                                            **self._kwargs)
    def join(self, *args):
         Thread.join(self, *args)
         return self._return
```

A code that used threading:

```
def my_func(str_lst, num, freq):
    df = []
    for i, y, f in zip(str_lst, num, freq):
        data = blp.bdp(i, flds=['xxx'], y, f)
        df.append(data)
        final_df = pd.concat(df)
    return final_df

Thread1 = ThreadWithReturnValue(target= my_func, args=(str_a, num_lst_a,freq_lst_a))
Thread2 = ThreadWithReturnValue(target= my_func, args=(str_b, num_lst_b,freq_lst_b))

Thread1.start()
Thread2.start()

output1 = Thread1.join()
output2 = Thread2.join()
```

The issue is that output1 has values from output 2 and output 2 has values from output 1 and missing output 2 values, that could be return only from the values that were passed to the thread 2, and vice versa.

Comment: You said, "it appears that some time the values from the thread 2 return has values from thread 1." How do you know that to be true. How are these values "returned" from the two threads. How do you know that the values are "mixed?" What code knows or cares whether they are "mixed?"

Comment: @SolomonSlow was a typo in the question, in the code itself there are different lists that are passed

Comment: @SolomonSlow because i see the return values with print(output1) and print(output2) and I can see some of the values with the string from list a in the return of output 2, but list a was not passed as an argument to thread 2, list b was passed. I put the class that returns values of join() method in the question

Comment: Sorry, I completely overlooked your `ThreadWithReturnValue` class. But one more question. What is `pd`? Are you using pandas? Is `pd` global? I don't know pandas, but if the two threads both are modifying the same global object, that could be bad. In any case, I probably can't help because like I said, I don't know pandas.

Comment: yeah, pd is pandas, the return output is from bloomberg as a dataframe, so once I print return values most of the time, not always, but most of the time, the data is mixed